# Haskell - Removing non-letter characters but ignoring white spaces?

Tags: haskell

I am very new to Haskell. I am trying to return a list of strings from a given string (which could contain non-letter characters) but I get a single string in the list.

The below code shows What I have tried so far:

```
toLowerStr xs = map toLower xs

--drop non-letters characters
dropNonLetters xs = words $ (filter (\x -> x `elem` ['a'..'z'])) $ toLowerStr xs
```

- lowercase all the characters by using `toLower` function
- remove non-letter characters by using `filter` function
- return a list of strings by using `words` function

I think the `filter` function is removing the white spaces and therefore it becomes a single string. I tried using `isSpace` function but I don't know exactly how to implement it in this case.

What is it that I am doing wrong? I get this output:

```
λ> dropNonLetters "ORANGE, apple! APPLE!!"
["orangeappleapple"]
```

But I want to achieve the below output:

```
λ> dropNonLetters "ORANGE, apple! APPLE!!"
["orange","apple","apple"]
```

Comment: What with tabs, ..

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem spaces between words

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I think the filter function is removing the white spaces and therefore it becomes a single string.

That is correct. As filter predicate you write `` \x -> x `elem` ['a'..'z'] ``. `['a'..'z']` is a list that contains lowercase letters, so for whitespace, the predicate will fail, and thus you should allow spaces as well.

We can for instance add the space character to the list:

```
dropNonLetters xs = words $ (filter (\x -> x `elem` (' ':['a'..'z'])))) $ toLowerStr xs
```

But this is inelegant and does not really explain itself. The `Data.Char` module however ships with two functions that are interesting here: [**`isLower :: Char -> Bool`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:isLower), and [**`isSpace :: Char -> Bool`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:isSpace). We can use this like:

```
dropNonLetters xs = words $ (filter (\x -> isLower x || isSpace x)) $ toLowerStr xs
```

`isLower` and `isSpace` are not only more "descriptive" and *elegant*. Usually these functions will be faster than a membership check (which will usually be done in *O(n)*), and furthermore it will also take into account tabs, new lines, etc.

We can also perform an *eta-reduction* on the function:

```
dropNonLetters = words . (filter (\x -> isLower x || isSpace x)) . toLowerStr
```

This then produces:

```
Prelude Data.Char> dropNonLetters "ORANGE, apple! APPLE!!"
["orange","apple","apple"]
```

I advise you to rename the function `dropNonLetters`, since now it does not fully explain that it will generate a list of words. Based on the name, I would think that it only drops non-letters, not that it converts the string to lowercase nor that it constructs words.

Comment: Thank you very much this worked and I will rename the function. You are missing `->` in the second block of the code.

Answer (score 1):

here's an example of separating characters into separate string lists:

> sortNumbers ::  [Char] -> [String]
>   sortNumbers args = filter (\strings ->strings/= "") $ zipWith (\x numbers -> filter (\char -> char == numbers) x) (repeat args)
>   ['1'..'9']